# Fine-tuning a model on sequences longer than the max sequence input length

Tags: huggingface-transformers, large-language-model, huggingface-trainer, text-generation

For a research I am doing, I am trying to fine-tune BioGPT-Large on data from WikiPathways, which are just pathways with all the genes that belong to that pathway. The max sequence length for BioGPT-Large is 1024, and most sequences are longer than that, even up to 30k tokens. I could ofcourse truncate all the sequences to 1024 or split the sequences into smaller chunks, but data would get lost that way. I am pretty stuck right now, any solutions?

I tried truncating and splitting into smaller chunks. Truncating result in the loss of information and splitting into chunks makes it so that information that is supposed to be in one sequence, gets split into smaller chunks and thus information is also lost.

Comment: maybe you need mamba based LLM https://www.kolaayonrinde.com/blog/2024/02/11/mamba.html

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how your data is encoded.
ea genetic code is just a few base pairs isnt it?.
a byte has 255 options.. but when it's used to text maybe you have less available.  Though you probably find something that works better than base64 encoding. Think of it though, as you will keep the pattern you feed it.

Another option, but this one is highly theoretical, almost philosophical perhaps.
Compress it zip it, bwah but that would destroy the sequences.. yes.
though zip files are unique too, they are the minimal representation of data.
As LLMs are behemoths in pattern detection (I never tested this ) perhaps it will work, as you end up with quite an essential data presentation of the pattern.  Which when zipped might require you to do again that re-encode to keep it within the allowed characters.

Another option but you tried it before the chunky way
make sure the chunks are from random positions, might take a lot longer to train but eventually it might learn to where chunks belong too, you might do it randomly, or fixed cuts, and add the cutting values as well tell it where the chunks where made, giving it some extra info to do its job.

Comment: Glutathione metabolism%WikiPathways_20240101%WP100%Homo sapiens https://www.wikipathways.org/instance/WP100 2687 2678 2687 2876 2936 290 2938 2946 2877 2937 2729 221357 3417 2678 2730 2678 2878 2953 290 26873 2687 2879 2539 2944

one sequence looks like this, every number being one gene

Comment: Okay my brother learned math at school to work with different numerical base systems, we mostly use base 10, and in development hex coding is base16, although it requires some custom encoding if you go alphabetical  a-z and A-Z that's base 48
and you can add the numbers as well but that would result in a shorter notation

Maybe include even more symbols #@$% just 3 characters would contain then anny number you can make out of 4 digits, Maybe 4 of such digits is able to encode 2 of the decimal versions (with a mask?)

the numbers are not that far appart (perhaps use delta values?)

Comment: hmm since you mentioned 1k vs 30k, above encoding wouldnt work.
I think the model has to learn the sets, i dont know what you try to achieve, but genetics like coding is  language, as a developer speaking i dont show it the whole code, but the parts i am interested in. 

If you are looking for squecences that are incommon, then there might be other tools better suited to it i think, also if you dont know what your looking for there are in neural nets methods to do heat mapping upon inputs (or upon sub layers) things like that.

Comment: or maybe https://www.kolaayonrinde.com/blog/2024/02/11/mamba.html

Comment: Hi! I am doing a research for my internship and I am trying to fine-tune a model to predict which pathway belongs to a set of genes, but the goal is to do this with the Transformer architecture. So mainly I think I am just looking for a way to compress information

Comment: Will you be able to compress it 30 times? I'm a bit doubtful but perhaps the set of gene numbers being used is smaller, then maybe dive into some compression logic then.
Notice it reminds me of chess tree search as well, also in chess positions, and neural nets who people train to label images. well there are probaply  more ways to do this.